# How can I decide up the nature of performed IO?

Tags: linux, performance-tuning, performance, io

- I am using Linux (3.2.12-3.2.4).
- I have few "syncer" processes which updates lots and lots SQLite db files  in a loop. The database sizes vary from 1 MB to few GB.
- I have a "searcher" process which can query those DBs and return matched results.

I am looking forward to tune some kernel parameters to get maximum IO performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your performance bottleneck is not the I/O but your choice of database engine. SQLite is just not designed for the kind of thing you're are doing and has pretty lousy performance even at the best of times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tuning sqlite at first? It's all dependent on your requirements but there's at least [PRAGMA synchronous](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) and lots more (googleable).